# RichEditor use execCommand('bold') twice append extra <span> label

Tags: javascript, html

I use execCommand('bold') to make the following text bold, but when I try it again to disable bold, then add other label like 'h' or something, It add extra  label link this:

```
<h1><span style="font-weight: normal;">111</span></h1>
```

I wonder how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

**It should works**
First of all if you really doing it correctly, it won't happen like that.

Please see the sample below, it should works.

```js
document.designMode = "on";

function myFunction(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 16) {
    // Press shift btn exec cmd for bold trigger
    document.execCommand("bold");
    
    //check in alert box when triggered
    //alert( document.getElementById("thebody").innerHTML );
    
    //check the updated code in console once triggered
    console.log( document.getElementById("thebody").innerHTML );
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onkeydown="myFunction(event)">
<div id="thebody">
<h1>Exec execCommand("Bold")</h1>

<p>Try to exec by pressing shift btn once highlighed</p>

<h2>Again execCommand("Bold")</h2>
<p>Select some text in this page, and press the SHIFT button to make the selected text toggle between bold and normal.</p>
</div>

<div id="preview">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note/Advise:** 
However, if your problem persists in your version of code, please share with me the function that trigger this `exec` `Cmd`.

Comment: My scene is a rich editor like `<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>`, I call `execCommand('Bold')` not only for change selection,but also change the following text inputted. The problem happens during I call bold twice(enable then disable bold input), and then start a `<h1>` lable input.

Answer (score 0):

javascript code is just like this:

```
Editor.setHeading = function(heading) {
    if(heading == 0){
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, '<div>')
    } else {
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, '<h'+heading+'>');
    }
}
Editor.setBold = function() {
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}
```

html is:

```
<body>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="editor.js"></script>
</body>
```